# Linq to Entities Only Select with Records

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to only select donors that have applicable donorsToActions items in the following Linq To Entities:

```
donors.SelectMany(Function(t) t.donorstoactions).GroupBy(Function(s) s.donor.id).[Select](function(p) New With { _
Key .donorname = p.key, _
Key .donoractions = p.Where(Function(j) j.action.event.id = "1").[Select](Function(k) New With { _
    Key .actionname = k.action.name, _
    Key .pledge = k.pledgeAmount, _
    Key .part = k.participant.name }) _
})
```

Currently, this pulls:
Donor1(), Donor2(group of donor actions), Donor3(), Donor4(), Donor5(group of donor actions)...

I would like it to not pull the donors that have no donoractions attached: Donor2(group of donor actions), Donor5(group of donor actions)

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Add `donors.Where(Function(t) t.donorstoactions.Any())`

Answer (score 0):

```
donorstoactions.Where(Function(a) a.action.event.id ="9").GroupBy(Function(b) b.donor).[Select](Function(c) New With { _
Key .DonorName = c.Key.firstname, _
Key .Actions = c.[Select](Function(d) New With { _
    Key .Name = d.action.name }) _
    })
```

This gives me something like this:

Group(Row1(Donor,Actions),Row2(Donor,Actions),Row3(Donor,Actions) ... Which would work, but I would much rather have

Group(Donor1(Actions),Donor2(Actions))